# Which regex to use for replacing new line if match?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to do next:

I have a large piece of data in notepad and using search/replace function I want to find text occurrence using some keyword and than replace new line with `""`.

E.g. using the keyword `optional`:

```
<-this is optional->
blalba
```

Expected result:

```
<-this is optional->
""
```

I tried `<-this is optional->\s*\n` but doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: doesn;t work ((

Comment: in simple words, I need regex for : if I meet something, for exaple word "optional", than next line should be replaced with empty "", if Im trying your regex nothing happend at all

Comment: Then try `(optional.*\R).*` --> `$1""`

Comment: Could you please clarify your question with better example.

Comment: @Anwar 
actual result:
<optional>
blabla
<optional>
blabla

expected:
<optional>
<optional>

every word is in a new line

Comment: So, does my latest suggestion work for you?

Comment: @Wiktor, nope, it deleted all but first line)

Comment: Do you mean you have *`.` matches newline* enabled? Tick it off and retry.

Comment: yes, mathces newline is enabled

Comment: Tick it off and retry `(optional.*\R).*` --> `$1""`

Comment: Wiktor, thx, works as charms, can you explain what kind of magic it is? how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
(optional.*\R).*
```

and replace with `$1""`.

**Details**:

- `(optional.*\R)` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern) capturing `optional` and then any 0+ chars other than line break symbols as many as possible (`.*`, the rest of the line), then a line break (`\R`)
- `.*` - the line below the line with `optional`

The `$1""` replacement inserts back the value captured into Group 1 and adds `""`.

The *`.` matches newline* option must be disabled.

Comment: can you advice some book or source which you think is good for regex learning?

Comment: See [Mastering Regular Expressions Powerful Techniques for Perl and Other Tools](http://ww2.ii.uj.edu.pl/~tabor/prII09-10/perl/master.pdf)